# An example of a sequence in $l^p$ that converges weakly not in a sense of norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Is there any example that a sequence in $l^p$ that converges weakly but not in a sense of norm for $1<p<\infty$??

There is a theorem that for $p=1$, if a sequence converges weakly, it converges in norm. This doesn't hold for $1<p<\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $e_i$ be the sequence with $1$ in the $i$-th place and $0$ elsewhere. Fix an arbitrary $p > 1$.

Then you can check that $e_i$ converges weakly to $0$ in $\ell^p$ as $i \to \infty$ using the characterisation $(\ell^p)^* \simeq \ell^q$ where $q$ is the Holder conjugate of $p$.  However we clearly have $\|e_i\| = 1 \not \to 0$.

This goes wrong if $p=1$ since then if $x \in \ell^\infty \simeq (\ell^1)^* $, we don't always have that $x_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you......!